# When load the data error rise Object of type Item is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

**Model.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    status_type = (
        ('a','Active'),
        ('d','Deactive')
    )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status_type, default = 'a')
    create_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
   def __str__(self):
        return self.name

  class PriceMaster(models.Model):
    status_type = (
        ('a','Active'),
        ('d','Deactive')
    )
    items = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gst = models.ForeignKey(Gst, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status_type, default = 'a')
    create_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.items)

    @property
    def cgst_unround(self):
        if not hasattr(self,'_cgst'):
            self._cgst = self.price * self.gst.gst / 100
        return round(self._cgst,2)

    @property
    def per_gst(self):
        self.per = self.gst.gst / 2
        return self.per

    @property
    def cgst(self):
        return round((self.cgst_unround / 2),2)

class TempCalculate(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    items_price = models.ForeignKey(PriceMaster,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    create_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    @property
    def item_price(self):
        self.price = self.items_price.price
        return self.price
```

** I'm trying to access item name **

```
@property
    def item_name(self):
        self.name = self.items_price.items
        return self.name
```

**Serializer.py I'm trying access item_name field**

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'

class TempCalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TempCalculate
        fields = ['id','item_name','quantity','item_price']
```

**api/view.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def TempItem(request):
    queryset = TempCalculate.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TempCalSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

**I'm trying access the item name but can't because when try to access the item name it's throw error Object of type Item is not JSON serializable. Any solution to load Foreign Key fields with rest framework.**

Comment: What is `item_name` in the `TemplCalculate` model? It has no `item_name` as far as the model says.

Comment: but TempCalculate model has Pricemaster ForeignKey Via this model can i access the item model name fields ??

Comment: `items_price` is not in the `fields` of your `TempCalSerializer`, you use `item_price`, the names make it a bit confusing...

Comment: I have 3 data table 1.item master it has name     2. price master it has ItemMaster foreign key   3.tempcalculte has PriceMaster Foreginkey now can I access item name via  PriceMaster foreginkey ??

Comment: if it is included in the `fields = ...`, yes, but here it isn't.